# Is ArcGIS Pro truncating of some legend titles documented?

Tags: legend, arcgis-pro, documentation

To understand what was causing a legend title to be truncated from "**What's on the map?**" to "**What's on the**" in an ArcGIS Pro 2.1.3 layout I developed the test below:

1. Start ArcGIS Pro
2. Create a new project using Map.aptx called TestProject in a new folder under C:\Temp
3. Add one layer to the map - in my test I used a countries shapefile (polygons) from Natural Earth but any shapefile or feature class should show this I think
4. No matter what your layer is called name it **ne_10m_admin_0_countries** (or something with more characters in its name)
5. Insert a Layout - I chose an A4 Portrait but any should be fine
6. Insert a Map Frame - I chose the only Map and the one with a scale rather than the Default but either should be fine
7. Make some room on the page for a legend under the map
8. Insert a Legend and position it by dragging out its rectangle under the map
9. Save the project and close ArcGIS Pro
10. Use IDLE (or your preferred Python IDE) to run the script below

---

```
import arcpy,os
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"C:\Temp\TestProject\TestProject.aprx")
lyt = aprx.listLayouts()[0]
legend = lyt.listElements('LEGEND_ELEMENT',"legend")[0]
legend.title = "What's on the map?"
legend.showTitle = True

lyt.exportToPDF(r"C:\Temp\test.pdf")
os.startfile(r"C:\Temp\test.pdf")
```

---

11. On the PDF that opens the legend title of "**What's on the map?**" appears in full
12. Close Adobe Acrobat Reader and the Python Shell window of IDLE to release any locks
13. Open the TestProject on ArcGIS Pro again
14. Rename the layer to **Countries**
15. Save the project and close ArcGIS Pro
16. Use IDLE (or your preferred Python IDE) to run the script again

This time when the PDF opens the legend title is truncated to "**What's on the**"

It appears that the length of the longest line of text next to the legend patches can restrict how many characters can appear the legend title.

Is this software behaviour documented anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just retested this using a later release of ArcGIS Pro and the issue is no longer present.

Consequently, it looks like it was fixed at some point after ArcGIS Pro 2.1.3.